# WinForms: Is any way to get window handle before Application.Run(new Form1())?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, handle

I have a winforms, **before Application.Run(new Form1())** I send message to other app

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern long SendMessage(IntPtr Handle, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

but I cannot get window handle, I tried:

```
IntPtr Handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
```

but sometime it returm wrong handle.
How can I do this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of the [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) function is the handle of the window that will receive the message.
[`Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.process.handle.aspx) returns the native handle of the current process. That's not a window handle.

[`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms157900.aspx) starts the message loop for the application. 
Since you want to send a message to another application your application doesn't need a message loop at all. You need however the handle to the other application's window.

The following example shows how to close the main window of another app using `SendMessage`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern long SendMessage(IntPtr Handle, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

public const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

private static void Main()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("OtherApp");
    if (processes.Length > 0)
    {
        IntPtr handle = processes[0].MainWindowHandle;
        SendMessage(handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to send a message to a *different* application then you need to get *its* window handle instead of the window handle belonging to your own process. Use `Process.GetProcessesByName` to find a specific process, and then use the `MainWindowHandle` property to get the window handle.  Note that `MainWindowHandle` is not the same as `Handle`, as the latter refers to the process handle rather than the window handle.